# Can't identify Syntax Error in my for loop

Tags: python

Getting syntax errors, can't identify why

```
elif num ==2:
    value = int(input("How many vowels does the word contain?"))
    if value == countVowels(item):
        score = score + 1
    print("Correct!")
else:
        print("Incorrect! Correct answer is", countVowels(item))        

elif num ==3:
    value = int(input("How many consonants does the word contain?"))
    if value == (len(item) - countVowels(item)):
        score = score + 1
    print("Correct!")
```

Receiving invalid syntax on the `elif` for `num==3` but can't identify why.

Comment: sorry for the noob question, beginner here

Comment: You can't have a `elif` after a `else`.

Comment: And do you even have `if` in a first place?

Answer (score 1):

```
    if value == countVowels(item):
        score = score + 1
    print("Correct!")
else:
        print("Incorrect! Correct answer is", countVowels(item))
```

This part looks like the indentation is all messed up.

Did you mean:

```
    if value == countVowels(item):
        score = score + 1
        print("Correct!")
    else:
        print("Incorrect! Correct answer is", countVowels(item))
```

?

Answer (score -1):

Your elif can't come after an else. The order should be like:

```
if <cond1>:

elif <cond2>:

elif <cond3>:

else:
```

The `if` is required to come first. Then you can optionally have one or more `elif`s and an optional `else` at the end.

To fix your code, you can put the else after the inner if:

```
elif num == 2:
    value = int(input("How many vowels does the word contain?"))
    if value == countVowels(item):
        score = score + 1
        print("Correct!")
    else:
       print("Incorrect! Correct answer is", countVowels(item))        

elif num == 3:
    value = int(input("How many consonants does the word contain?"))
    if value == (len(item) - countVowels(item)):
        score = score + 1
        print("Correct!")
    else:
        print("Incorrect! Correct answer is", countVowels(item))
```